# Summary of recent results presentation slide: proper citation

Tags: presentation

In some conference presentations a slide with a summary of recent progress in the field is included. One way to do it is to present a graph, where the recent results are compared in terms of some parameter. I was wondering what are the good ways to properly reference all the publications. Needless to say, a full citation of every result (let's say there are 20 results from several different groups compared) would definitely take up too much space in the slide. So, how much information is enough for the publication to be properly referenced (i.e. name of the first author + publication venue + date)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First author plus year.

However, if you present 20 results from 20 groups, you are not doing an introduction, you are starting a review paper.
On the other hand, if you are presenting 20 results, but they are actually only 4 parameters from 5 groups ... you are still doing a review!

Focus on the 2-3 most recent results relevant to *your* work. Show that you are either on par with the best ones, or that you have something very different with respect to the most recent (and you have good reasons for that).